# Decorator passing arguments as KWARGS but need positional args in flask API end point

Tags: python, flask, decorator, python-decorators

I have a flask application with many endpoints and I planning to write a decorator which will log the actions of APIs end points.

For example, I have a end point to delete an entry as below for API call http://localhost:5000/api/owners/123/delete

```
@route('/owners/<ownerid>/delete',methods=['DELETE'])
def deleteOwner(ownerid):
     if request.method == 'DELETE':
         """ delete action """
         return jsonify({})
```

Now I want to add a decorator to this call so it logs the user actions. So I am trying out with a decorator as below

```
def logtrail(func):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        print args
        print kwargs.values()  #This prints {"ownerid":"123"}
        return func(kwargs)
    return wrap
```

Now decorating as below

```
@route('/owners/<ownerid>/delete',methods=['DELETE'])
@logtrail
def deleteOwner(ownerid):
     if request.method == 'DELETE':
         """ delete action """
         return jsonify({})
```

When I decorate my original API method with @logtrail, the "ownerid" which I need as a positional argument is passed as {"ownerid":"123"} to the decorator function.

I am new to decorators and need some help on how to approach this.

Comment: Do be careful in how you write your decorators as your simplistic implementation will break introspection and potentially cause other issues. You may want to consider looking at a decorator module such as ``wrapt`` which uses techniques to ensure your decorators behave properly. See http://wrapt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ Read through the blogs posts given there for an explanation of the problems that can arise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related on how variables works / arguments are passed on python.
To fix it, just change  `return func(kwargs)` to `return func(**kwargs)`, so the kwargs will be passed as keywords instead of a dict.

```
def logtrail(func):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        print args
        print kwargs.values()  #This prints {"ownerid":"123"}
        return func(**kwargs)
    return wrap
```